# ACF Fields are not showing up on Homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I want to Customize the Yith Plugin for which I want to add some custom fields with Existing fields. I am getting fields from ACF and adding them to an array ACF Fields are showing up in Yith Setting but only a few are showing up in the Homepage and other site pages.

```
add_filter('yith_woocompare_standard_fields_array','ta_yith_woo_compare');
function ta_yith_woo_compare($fields){      
    $acf_fields_groups = acf_get_fields(5258);
    $labels = array();
    foreach($acf_fields_groups as $grp)
    {
        $group_id = $grp['ID'];
        $sub_fields = $grp['sub_fields'];
        foreach($sub_fields as $fld){
            $labels[$fld['name']] = $fld['label'];
        }
    }

    $fields =$fields + $labels;
    return $fields;
}
```

Similarly, if I print Array Yith Setting Page print array with all fields.
[image]

while on Homepage only a few fields returned!
[image]

I don't know this is an issue with Array or ACF, please help me to solve this problem, here is my code.

Comment: Please do not include images of code, your question should include the code itself in formatted in code blocks.

Comment: I have added the code at Bottom. It was necessary to elaborate my problem using Screenshots.

Comment: I have moved code snippet to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out this by changing the following code from compare.php in Yith Plugin.

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $field => $name) : ?>
<th>
    <?php if ($field != 'image') echo esc_html( $name); ?>
</th>
.
.
.
```

Changed to this =>

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $field => $name) : ?>
<th>
    <?php if ($field != 'image') echo esc_html( $field ); ?>
</th>
.
.
.
```